# Variable assignment in command substitution

Tags: bash

Let's say we have a command output a variable assignment string, say 'var=foo', if I put this command in Command Substitution which looks like 
 **`$(echo var=foo)`**, it causes 'command not found' error.

```
[223212 dot@anne ~]$ var=foo
[223226 dot@anne ~]$
[223230 dot@anne ~]$ $(var=foo)
[223235 dot@anne ~]$
[223236 dot@anne ~]$ $(echo var=foo)
bash: var=foo: command not found
[223240 dot@anne ~]$
[224909 dot@anne ~]$ $(echo ls)
a    b    c   d    
[225036 dot@anne ~]$
[225110 dot@anne ~]$ $(echo $(var=foo))
[225116 dot@anne ~]$
```

Since we can directly put variable assignment in Command Substitution like this **`$(var=foo)`** (though it's meaningless I think), and **`$(echo ls)`** works as expected as well, **why output a assignment in Command Substitution causing error?**

This is `man bash` about Command Substitution:

> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the
>   command name.
>
> Bash  performs  the expansion by executing command in a
>   subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the
>   standard output of the command, with any trailing newlines deleted.

As I understand it, **`$(echo var=foo)`** should be replace by **`var=foo`** just like **`$(var=foo)`**.

Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: when you use command substitution you should assign the output to something, i.e. `foo=$(echo buzz)`. Of course "echo" doesn't make such sense here, it doesn't require a command substitution usually, you would normally just use `foo=buzz`

Comment: That's interesting, it looks like Bash considers the output of the subprocess to be a command name, not an other instruction. It's like if you had typed `var\=foo`, thus the command not found error. Try to eval the result to fix this: `eval $(echo var=foo)`.

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, and I know may be I can use eval to sovle problem like this. But that's not the point. Using echo is just an easy example, actually I'm using $(gpg -qd file).

Comment: If you're using `$(pgp -qd file)`, then you're presumably running into the issues described in detail in [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) (as a command generated from an unquoted command substitution has the exact same caveats as one generated via the unquoted expansion of a string).

Comment: There's a reason that the calling convention for `ssh-agent` (a tool which emits code to be run by the calling shell on its stdout) is `eval "$(ssh-agent)"`. There are also [good reasons](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) tools following that convention need to be defensively written, and trusted by their users; if you were designing the mechanism to save and restore shell variables from whole cloth, using a NUL-delimited stream is much safer, and actually easier to implement at generation time if your only platform is Linux, as `/proc/self/environ` is in exactly that format.

Comment: @Pawamoy, nothing surprising about it -- the only parse stages unquoted expansion results go through is string-splitting and globbing; assignments are recognized before that point. `eval` may be well what the OP wants, but it's [dangerous](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and best not recommended without explicit caveats.

Comment: (This design is critical to security: If expansion results went through the whole parsing process, it would be next to impossible to handle untrusted data safely in shell).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's `man bash`:

```
SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION
   When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the fol‐
   lowing expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to
   right.

   1.     The  words  that  the  parser  has  marked  as variable
          assignments (those  preceding  the  command  name)  and
          redirections are saved for later processing.

   2.     The words that are not variable assignments or redirec‐
          tions are expanded.  If any words remain  after  expan‐
          sion,  the  first  word  is taken to be the name of the
          command and the remaining words are the arguments.
   [...]
```

In your case, the simple command has a single word `$(echo var=foo)`.

Since there are no words marked as variable assignments (because this word is instead a command substitution), step 1 doesn't apply.

We then move on to step 2, where the word `$(echo var=foo)` is expanded into `var=foo`. We don't go back to the first step, we just do what step 2 says: "take the first word as the name of the command".

This is why `var=foo` is executed as a command instead of being interpreted as an assignment.

Comment: If so, how about $(var=foo)? $(var=foo) is a single word and obviously is not going to be marked as variable assignments as well, then to step 2...

Comment: @dotc, `var=foo` has no output when it's run, so `$(var=foo)` is  equivalent to `$()`, which does nothing.

Comment: @dotc, ...what do you mean "obviously is not going to be marked as variable assignments"? That command *is indeed* an assignment.

Comment: @dotc There are two simple commands in this case, `$(..)` and `var=foo`. One is executed as part of building the other, and each follow the steps above.

Comment: I get the point. I believe this is the answer. Thank you guys!

Comment: @thatotherguy; Why there is only one word in `echo var=foo`? I think there are two words: `echo` and `var=foo`, isn't it?

Comment: @haccks There are two words in `echo var=foo`, but there is only one word in `$(echo var=foo)` (a single command substitution, regardless of what it contains).

Comment: @thatotherguy; Can you explain a bit more about the expansion? As I understand what you explained, the word `$(echo var=foo)` will be expanded to `var=foo`. But what I think that `echo var=foo` will be parsed fist as per simple command rule and then the `$(echo var=foo)` will become `$(var=foo)`. (sorry for the silly question. I just started to learn the bash grammar :) )

Comment: @haccks `$(echo var=foo)` will become `var=foo`. It will not become `$(var=foo)`. `echo var=foo` *outputs* `var=foo`, but it isn't replaced with `var=foo` in any sense.

Comment: So when you said one word in `$(echo var=foo)`, that mean `var=foo` after the expansion of `$(echo var=foo)` ?

Comment: @haccks "word" has a special meaning in shell grammar. `man bash` describes it as "A sequence of characters considered as a single unit by the shell.  Also known as a token." `$(echo var=foo)` is an example of a word, and it undergoes expansion to become zero or more different words (the single word `var=foo` in this case)

Comment: Ignore the last comment. Can you please just elaborate [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453219/variable-assignment-in-command-substitution/49453377?noredirect=1#comment85910272_49453377)  for `$(echo var=foo)`?

Comment: @haccks `$(echo var=foo)` is a simple command with a single word. In step 1, we check for assignments and redirections. `$(echo var=foo)` is not an assignment or redirection, it's just a command substitution. Then we move on to step 2. As part of expansion, we run `echo var=foo`, capture its result (the string `var=foo`), and substitute it. We now have the word `var=foo`. However, we don't start from the top and begin parsing this as an assignment. We're still in step 2. Step 2 says that "if any words remain [..], the  first  word  is taken to be the name of the command", so we run it as a cmd

Comment: @thatotherguy; OK. Actually said `$(..)` and `echo var=foo` are two simple command and each will follow the above steps. So I thought first the steps will be followed by `echo var=foo` and then `$(..)` which doesn't seem true as per your last comment.